# upgraded libtiff is now causing error while starting django server

Tags: python, django, gdal, libtiff

So I recently performed a brew upgrade/update and post that I have been seeing the following error while starting my django server

```
    OSError: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib, 0x0006): Library not loaded: /usr/local/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib
  Referenced from: <33E7E7D2-EDA5-33CC-AFB4-2F35C8A1E369> /usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.32.3.6.4.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/libtiff/4.5.1/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/libtiff/4.5.1/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/libtiff/4.5.1/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libtiff.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

When checking in the respective location, I'm seeing that the libtiff file that my system has is

```
$ pwd
/usr/local/homebrew/opt/libtiff/lib
$ ls
libtiff.6.dylib     libtiffxx.6.dylib   pkgconfig
libtiff.a       libtiffxx.a
libtiff.dylib       libtiffxx.dylib


$ pwd
/usr/local/opt/gdal/lib
$ ls
cmake           libgdal.32.dylib    python3.11
gdalplugins     libgdal.dylib
libgdal.32.3.6.4.dylib  pkgconfig
```

So it seems as if my system is looking for `libtiff.5.dylib` but my current version installed is `libtiff.6.dylib`.

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem started when i installed the new mac os 17, sanoma and non of my libraries was working.

This fixed it for me.

1. uninstall homebrew `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"`
2. install Homebrew again `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"`
3. Reinstall the commands to run your django server (php in my case)

Answer (score 0):

Just because of how much time I spent today trying to solve the issue of getting Python to run `libtiff.5.dylib` and not `libtiff.6.dylib` today, I'm posting this answer.  It's not specific to Django Server, but it is specific to `libtiff`.  I'm running Mac OS Sonoma 14.1.

I think the problem is that Homebrew just doesn't play nice with some versions of Python libraries.  After repeatedly getting the dreaded `cannot create wheel` error trying to install `libtiff` again and again what I finally did is install and upgrade Conda and restart my terminal.  Worked like a charm.

My guess is that worked because Conda is more Python-specific than Homebrew, so it properly installed and linked all of the relevant libraries that Homebrew could not.  But that's just a guess.